# Withdraw without handling result

Tags: solidity

I have this function:

```
function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
    require(payable(msg.sender).send(address(this).balance));
}
```

I see in others contracts this form of the same function:

```
function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
    (bool success, bytes memory data) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    require(success);
}
```

As I know, if the require fails, `value` isn't deducted from the contract's balance, isn't true?

If so, what's the need of handling the result? There maybe a security issue using the first one without it?

Thanks

Comment: I do not see return statement in your question.

Comment: @Itération122442 fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two examples use different means of transferring value. Also, they obviously have different return data: one has only one return value, while the other has two return values.

If there are two return values, you can't simply inline the `require`, since `require` needs its first parameter to be of type `bool`. In the case of two return values, the first parameter would be of type `(bool, bytes)` (a tuple).

So, if there are two return values, you have to first assign the needed value to a variable and after that check its value in a `require`.

And, yes, if the contract reverts (such as `require` does if it fails), everything is reverted back to original - it's like the transaction had never even occurred.

Comment: Thanks.  If I true understand, both functions do the same action and both work, the only difference is how they invoke the `payable` function, isn't true?

Comment: They're not exactly the same, but yes they both transfer assets. The  `payable` function is invoked with both methods.